# Enumerate / interact with WPF Windows and Controls from a separate process

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility

Quite a while ago I developed a test automation system that unfortunately none of the frameworks that existed at the time could fulfill.

One of the key functions is its ability to find and interact with Win32 dialogs leveraging the standard Win32 API's (EnumWindows, FindWindowEx, etc...).

A team recently introduced a WPF app into the mix due to changes in Windows 8 and I started what I thought would be a simple task of finding the window, enumerating the controls (looking for the OK button) and clicking it. It is important to note that my system does not invoke the app under test. It is a system level event and essentially I need to "find it" and "close it" via the OK button due to the code path it takes.

I quickly realized that this is not as straight forward as I thought but I know its possible because with Snoop I can both find the window and drill down the control tree until I find it. There are quite a few questions on the topic but they are all within the same app/appdomain.

In my case, this is happening from a wholly separate application (.net 4). I know the windows title but little else.

Does anyone know how to achieve what essentially Snoop is doing (find a window, get a list of its controls, traverse it looking for a specific control by some criteria) and then simulating the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it, but you might be looking for [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From that page:

> Microsoft UI Automation is the new accessibility framework for
>   Microsoft Windows. It addresses the needs of assistive technology
>   products and automated test frameworks by providing programmatic
>   access to information about the user interface (UI). In addition, UI
>   Automation enables control and application developers to make their
>   products accessible.